# Problem yacc in golang: syntax error: unexpected $end

Tags: go, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

A cordial greeting.

I'm learning yacc in golang and i created this file:

```
%{

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

%}

%union{
    ex string
}

%token <ex> DB OTHER_DB

%% 
query:  other
        |
        db
        ;

db:     DB
        {
            fmt.Printf("\tDB: %s\n", $1 )
        }
        ;

other:  OTHER_DB
        {
            fmt.Printf("\tOTHER_DB: %s\n", $1 )
        }
        ;
%% 

type mlex struct {
    expr   string
    result int
}

func (f *mlex) Lex(lval *yySymType) int {
    yyErrorVerbose = true
    return 0
}

func (f *mlex) Error(s string) {
    fmt.Printf("syntax error: %s\n", s)
}

func Parse(expr string) int {
    m := &mlex{expr, 0}
    yyParse(m)
    return m.result
}
```

but when executing it I get this error:

> syntax error: syntax error: unexpected $end, expecting DB or OTHER_DB

I have been testing this yacc file with this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    res := Parse("db")
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

**What could it be ? Will I need anything else in the yacc file?**

I am trying to make a very simple, fully functional example to understand it well.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

When your parser needs to know what the next input symbol ("token") is, it calls the `yyLexer`'s `Lex` method. Your implementation of that makes no attempt to read a token. Instead, it just returns 0:

```
func (f *mlex) Lex(lval *yySymType) int {
    yyErrorVerbose = true
    return 0
}
```

So from the parser's perspective, it is being given an empty input stream, regardless of what input you might actually have provided. It then attempts to parse this empty input, but your grammar doesn't permit it. The only valid inputs start with the tokens `DB` or `OTHER_DB`, and it doesn't see either of those things.

So it produces the error message, detailing exactly what its problem is. (The parser represents the end of input with the internal pseudo-token `$end`, in case that was confusing you.)

Comment: oh ok. thanks for you answer.
I have a theoretical emptiness. The examples that i found are confusing for me and complex for someone who is starting and other example are with C language.


How would you make a simple implementation of this?

Comment: I did a search for "golang goyacc lexical analysis". I can't say the results were perfect. Many of them were pretty complicated; others were reimplementations of flex by people who may or may not have any expertise in the area and in any case don't document well. And others don't actually use goyacc despite it being in the search. However, [GopherCon 2018 - How to Write a Parser in Go](https://about.sourcegraph.com/go/gophercon-2018-how-to-write-a-parser-in-go) is actually about writing simple parsers using goyacc and includes code for several small lexers. Good luck.

Comment: @stivenson. **Note:** I'm not endorsing the tutorial in the previous comment. In fact, SO guidelines recommend not asking for (or providing) links to tutorials, because they tend to be opinionated. I actually have no opinion on that link, since I'm not a Go programmer and I didn't read it thoroughly. Still, it might help you. From a *theoretical* perspective, you might find that a book or other resource about parsing theory is helpful, even if Go is not the target language. The theoretical concepts are the same.